# Add button + text in Infragistics ultragrid column

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid, wingrid

I am using Infragistics 2013 version.
I have a requirement wherein I have to add a button along with a text in a column in winforms ultragrid. 
The button will open a pop up screen which allows user to select a value that will be displayed as a text in the grid's column.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok got the answer. 

Had to set the columns style to EditButton. 

    UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ColName").Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.EditButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got the answer.

Had to set the columns style to EditButton.

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ColName").Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.EditButton
```

Answer (score 6):

Set the [Style](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~Style.html) of the Column to [ColumnStyle](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.html).EditButton.  For example:

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ColName").Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.EditButton
```

You can then handle the UltraGrids [CellButtonClicked](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~ClickCellButton_EV.html) event to know when the button was clicked where e.Cell will let you know what cell was clicked:

```
Private Sub UltraGrid1_ClickCellButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs) Handles ultraGrid1.ClickCellButton
   Debug.WriteLine("Button in " & e.Cell.Value.ToString() & " cell was clicked.")
End Sub
```

Comment: The second part of the problem was adding **text** to the cell.  To achieve this, handle the grid event `InitializeRow`.  See Mike Saltzman's response
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/61866.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend the answer slightly:  If you want the button to be visible all the time (rather than just when you click into the cell containing the button) you may also need to set the ButtonDisplayStyle:

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ColName").ButtonDisplayStyle = UltraWinGrid.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
```

Also, if you want more control over the button's appearance or location then this info from Mike Saltzman from Infragistics may be useful:

> If you want buttons that are left-aligned, more than one button in the
>   same cell, or buttons that don't fill the entire cell but contain text
>   and/or images, you can use an editor. The basic approach is something
>   like this:
>
> 1) Add an editor control to your form (like UltraTextEditor, for
>   example).
>
> 2) Use the ButtonsLeft and/or ButtonsRight collection to add the
>   buttons you want. You can set the Text and Appearance of each button.
>
> 3) In code, set the EditorControl of the Column (or Cell) to the
>   editor control. This is essentially like setting the Style but in a
>   more robust way.
>
> 4) To handle the click events of the button(s), you handle the events
>   on the editor - not the grid. For example, if it's just a normal
>   button, you would use EditorButtonClick. The event args will pass you
>   a Context which will return the grid cell in which the button was
>   clicked.

Answer (score 0):

its easy.

```
 private void ultraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // We only need to do this the first time the row is initialized.
            if (e.ReInitialize == false)
            {
                e.Row.Cells["Button"].Value = "Click Here";
            }
        }
        }
```